# Capturar posição das articulações nos eixos X,Y,Z com o Kinect V2

Tags: c#, c++, imagem, kinect

Preciso extrair a posição das articulações de uma gravação e/ou em tempo real, e converter para formato de banco de dados e/ou arquivo (txt) . Parecido com o que é feito neste [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tOe_kfeH8Y), mas ao invés de exibir preciso salvar os valores dos eixos X,Y,Z para cada uma das 26 articulações.

Na documentação fornecida pela microsoft é dado mostra como fazer o rastreamento em tempo real, mas não como extrair os dados brutos destas variáveis.

[Rastrear corpo 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn799273.aspx)

[Rastrear corpo 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyindexframe.aspx)

Caso não tenha como salvar, como posso extrair estes dados direto do formato padrão dos arquivos gravados pelo Kinect Studio (formatos `.xrf` e `.xef`)?

Quero também saber a diferença entre as classes `BodyIndexFrame`, `BodyFrame` e `Body`

O script pra pegar esses dados pode ser feito em qualquer linguagem, mas imagino que vá ser feito em C++/C# como o funcionamento de todo resto.

Comment: Hum... me parece que faltou você ler a documentação com atenção. Eu não manjo muito do Kinect, mas no primeiro link que você cita tem o uso da estrutura [`CameraSpacePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx)...

Comment: Realmente, estava procurando por uma classe que fizesse isso, não diretamente pela estrutura, muito obrigado.

Comment: Oi novamente. Se você puder postar uma resposta com a sua conclusão/solução, seria ótimo. Assim a sua pergunta deixa de constar como ainda não respondida e pode ajudar mais facilmente outras pessoas no futuro (fora que você ganha reputação por isso). :) Eu pensei em postar uma, mas eu não tenho o ambiente pra testar um exemplo mínimo que funcione para o que você pede.

Comment: Estou construindo o código, assim que conseguir fazer isso com precisão posso postar. Pensei nisso não só pelo fato de completar a resposta, mas pelo fato da comunidade brasileira que desenvolve para kinect não ser muito grande   e/ou participatva ...

Comment: Solução devidamente detalhada.

Comment: Muito legal! Ganhou os meus +1. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Não é possível extrair a posição de arquivos `.xrf` e `.xef`.
- [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.aspx) é a classe que contém o estado e a posição (eixos x, y e z) de todas as articulações de uma pessoa A sendo rastreada.
- [BodyFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyframe.aspx) é a classe usada para guardar a stream de saída do
  Kinect V2 (dados brutos) de cada corpo sendo rastreado.
- [BodyIndexFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyindexframe.aspx) é a classe que faz o casting de BodyFrame para a
  interpretação e exibição dos dados na saída padrão.
- A posição das articulações se encontram em Body.Joints.Values.Position.[X, Y ou Z], [exemplo aqui](https://github.com/inessadl/Kinect2Arff/blob/master/KinectFileManager#L60).

---

Segue solução.

> https://github.com/inessadl/Kinect2Arff

É uma implementação a partir de outra, referenciada no próprio README do projeto. 
O projeto irá para receber várias funcionalidades no período de curto-médio prazo.